# MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.3.4 download failed

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mysql-connector

Can somebody tell me why is it failed.  Today I installed MySQL on my Win 7 64bit laptop. I downloaded MySQL community server 5.6.20 and during download and installation I got an error that it failed to download Connector/ODBC 5.3.4.

Can somebody help me fix this. I want to use MySQL for visual studio 2013 for my VB project. 
Also MySQL for Visual Studio 1.1.4 not installed and I don't know if that is required at all. Couple of  items are there under this, like Core components,  Visual Studio Integration, Entity Framework Designer Integration. When I hover over this it shows a tip as it requires visual studio 2008, 2010, 2012 but it was not found on this machine.... I am using VS 2013. What am I supposed to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could manage to get it work by installing a couple of patches (mysql-connector-odbc-3.51.30-winx64) and (mysql-for-visualstudio-1.2.3). It's now up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Check if MySQL Connector/ODBC is missing from the manifest.

If that's the case, a workaround is to manually download and [install the connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/).